# PHP string concatenation problem?

Tags: php, string, concatenation, echo

```
function formatUpdate($tweet,$dt,$picture,$username)
{
    if(is_string($dt)) $dt=strtotime($dt);

    $tweet=htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($tweet));


       $at = "@" . $username;




    return'
    <li>
    <a href="nano.com/' . $username . '"><img class="avatar" src="images/' . $picture . '" width="48" height="48" alt="avatar" /></a>
    <div class="tweetTxt">
    <strong><a href="nano.com/' . $username . '">' . $username . '</a></strong> '. preg_replace('/((?:http|https|ftp):\/\/(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?[^\s\"\']+)/i','<a href="$1" rel="nofollow" target="blank">$1</a>',$tweet).'
    <div class="date">'.relativeTime($dt).'</div> <a class ="reply"  href="?replyto=' echo $at;   '">reply</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>';

}
```

Comment: The code in your question is very poorly formatted and the last line is a syntax error in itself. I'm not even sure if mattbasta's edit did anything to improve it. Could you paste the full code?

Comment: this is just part of the code, i just wanted to show you snippets of the code to prove my questions!!

Comment: Well, the way your code looks right now, you're neither assigning the string to a variable nor echoing it. If your code looks like that, there's the issue.

Comment: what do you mean by " values in properly"? can you add the error message or the current result + expected result.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Showing the snippet doesn't seem to have made the question clear at all, because the snippet has syntax errors. You need to close the string and end with a semicolon. Did you mean to echo the string?

Comment: the reply parameter in the url, its mean to have the value @username, can you give me cleaner way of doing it, if my code is poorly formatted, sorry for being a newbie @BOLTOCK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append the value of a variable to a string you need not echo the variable.

You have

```
href="?replyto=' echo $at;   '">reply</a>
```

Change it to

```
href="?replyto='. $at .'">reply</a>
```

Comment: your right thanks, but the problem it on the page it shows a @username instead of "reply" link? its wierd. i think im doing the concat wrong

Answer (score 1):

bolt is right. often concat issue has to do with a confusion of mixed in code, literals, and closing quotes/double-quotes. try to use heredoc instead to clean up your code-block.

for example, i would do the following to save my eyes staring at the code and to save my mind from insanity trying to find where the syntax error is (pseudo-coding only):

```
$at = "@$username";
$rt = relativeTime($dt);

$out = <<<raw
    <div class="date">$rt</div>
    <a class ="reply" href="?replyto=$at">reply</a>
raw;
```

just look at how much simpler it looks eh?

to learn about heredoc here's a reading reference.

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc